# Cannot build QT from sources with libc++ from conan-center recipe. (qglobal.h:45:12: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found)

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, libc++

I'm trying to build `qt/5.15.2@` package from conan-center with that profile:

```
[settings]
build_type=Debug
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
compiler=clang
compiler.version=9
compiler.libcxx=libc++
[env]
CC=clang-9
CXX=clang++-9
CXXFLAGS="-v"
```

it fails with that output

```
Performing shadow build...
Preparing build tree...
Creating qmake...
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/qmake/main.cpp:30:
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/qmake/project.h:32:
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/qmake/library/qmakeevaluator.h:36:
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/qmake/library/qmakeparser.h:32:
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/qmake/library/qmake_global.h:32:
In file included from /home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1:
/home/user/conan/qt/5.15.2/my/my/source/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:45:12: fatal error: 'type_traits' file
      not found
#  include <type_traits>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I already tried a lot of things to solve it:

1. Add `-I /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/c++/v1/` to `./configure`. The help of configure says that it is acceptable to pass `-I`, `-D`, `-L` parameters
2. Define `INCLUDE` or `INCLUDEPATH` env variables with the value of `/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/c++/v1/`
3. Add the same thing as in (1) to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` in `./configure` call
   All approaches above don't work, the output is still the same

The path `/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/c++/v1/` contains all stdlib headers and `type_traits` too. Other conan packages are building fine, adding `-v` option to compiler shows a list of include paths which contains the path above.
I also tried to add `-v` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` to trace include paths but it doesn't even change anything
I found some similar questions but they're all related to android's NDK which I don't use